# Selecting a specific table from a database from a text box

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am trying to allow the user to select which table they want to take their data from, the UserID text box(UserIDtb) is where the user inputs the table they want. I've tried several different ways of doing it but cant seem to allow the user to select a specific table. This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ConfirmIDButt.Click
    Chart1.Series.Add("Score")
    Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dataFile = "\users.accdb" ' Change it to your Access Database location
    Conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
    Conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Month], [Score] FROM [Table]", Conn)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Chart1.Series("Score").Points.AddXY(dr("Month").ToString, dr("Score").ToString)
    End While
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have time to fully answer, but the line you need to focus on is `Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Month], [Score] FROM [Table]", Conn)`.You'll want to validate the table name somehow as bad user input could turn into a database problem, so also lookup "SQL Injection Attack". If you know the names of the tables ahead of time, a list they pick from would be at least better than a text box.

Comment: IDK but for some reason I think its poor UI decisions to allow them to pick what table the query is going to be built from. Unless the end users have a thorough understanding of the DB structure itself, you should be making those decisions for them. I am of course making a lot of assumptions here, but it just seems weird to me. I could also be really dumb too so whatever

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, its a school project and the aim of the program is to allow the student to view their grades in a graph form, but there is also a teacher section in which the teacher should be able to select which student they wish to view, I will try and implement a table however, thanks!